# Loop through multiple objects and get similar key values in new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I have array of objects and I am trying to loop through them and have similar key values in new object here is example of data that I have.

```
let newDats = [{"ID":1, "Name": "Ahmed", "Age":17, "Score":84, "Absentee":3}, 
{"ID":2, "Name": "Hassan", "Age":15, "Score":87, "Absentee":2},
{"ID":3, "Name": "Aisha", "Age":18, "Score":86, "Absentee":2}]
```

And so on. However, what I want is something as:

```
data = [{ID:[1,2,3], Names:["Ahmed", "Hassan","Aisha"], 
Ages:[17,15,18]}]
```

And so forth. My end goal is to perform basic descriptive statistics on the numeric parts of the data so if there is better ideas I would love to hear I am knida newbie to js .

PS

Column names (object keys ) can be more than this and unknown so I want something dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define  "similar key values " In your example, what makes ID key different then Score?! Why did you group just ID, name And ages.... Not the rest?! And what are the: " basic descriptive statistics on the numeric parts " Why would you even need to group data for that like you did?

Comment: I just meant those as an example I really want group all keys like that.

Comment: And by similar key values I mean Ids, names and so on like I have show below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function below. Just pass the `array` you want to sort.

```js
function dataSorter(dataArr) {
  const data = {};
  for (const item in dataArr[0]) data[item] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
    for (const item in dataArr[i]) {
      data[item].push(dataArr[i][item]);
    }
  }

  return data;
}

/* Example Below */

let newDats = [{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "Ahmed",
    Age: 17,
    Score: 84,
    Absentee: 3
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    Name: "Hassan",
    Age: 15,
    Score: 87,
    Absentee: 2
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    Name: "Aisha",
    Age: 18,
    Score: 86,
    Absentee: 2
  },
];

console.log(dataSorter(newDats));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* Ignore this */
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```js
let newDats = [{"ID":1, "Name": "Ahmed", "Age":17, "Score":84, "Absentee":3}, 
{"ID":2, "Name": "Hassan", "Age":15, "Score":87, "Absentee":2},
{"ID":3, "Name": "Aisha", "Age":18, "Score":86, "Absentee":2}];

data = {};
keys = [];

for(let keyVal in newDats[0]) {
    keys.push(keyVal)
    data[keyVal] = [];
}

newDats.forEach(dt => {
    keys.forEach( kv => {
        data[kv].push(dt[kv])
    })
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Assuming all objects in newDats have the same key names

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array of objects, iterating over all [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of each element and pushing them to the property array of the accumulator. This allows for each object having different keys.

```js
let newDats = [{ "ID": 1, "Name": "Ahmed", "Age": 17, "Score": 84, "Absentee": 3 }, { "ID": 2, "Name": "Hassan", "Age": 15, "Score": 87, "Absentee": 2 }, { "ID": 3, "Name": "Aisha", "Age": 18, "Score": 86, "Absentee": 2 }];

const result = newDats.reduce((acc, o) => (
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => (acc[k] ??= []).push(o[k])), acc), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

*Note the use of the [logical nullish assignment operator (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) which can be replaced by a logical OR short circuit for compatibility.*

```
//acc[k] ??= []
acc[k] = acc[k] || []
```